# how can custom scripts be added in index.html's head part in docusaurus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docusaurus

I created a scripts folder inside static and added a custom js file called "GetLocation.js" and here is the path for it **project/website/static/scripts/GetLocation.js**

I see there is a place in siteconfig.js to add custom scripts and adding it here doesn't work

```
scripts: [
    
    'https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js',
    
     "/scripts/GetLocation.js"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Refreshing the cache worked